# Solution of system of linearly dependent equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

So, I have the system of equations $x'(t) = Ax$ where $A$ is first row-(4,-2) and second row - (8,-4). This has two eigenvalues, both are 0. But I tried to solve it this way:

$x_1' = 4x_1 -2x_2$

and

$x'_2 = 8x_1 -4x_2$


Next, I multiplied the top equation by 2 and got $2x_1' = 8x_1 - 4x_2$
Then I equated $2x_1'$ and $x_2'$ so $2x_1' = x_2'$ and integrating both sides I have $2x_1 = x_2$. 
So, it seems to me that the solution should just be $x_1 = f(x)$ and $x_2 = 2f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is any arbitrary function. But apparently that isn't valid. I'm sure I'm missing something huge/obvious but I'm lost as to why that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you learned characteristic polynomial for eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yeah, and i know how to do it that way, but I don't get why this way wouldn't work.

Comment: Your solution is correct in that regard. We get two eigenvalues that are both zero. However, the approach to find the solution is not correct as you wouldn't be able to use a general function. It would not satisfy the equation in general.

Comment: Wow, I just realized why that doesn't work. I was basically just solving for the eigenvector. So, yeah.... Pretty idiotic mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just realizing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have the system:

$$x'(t) = Ax = \begin{bmatrix}4 & -2\\8 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

If we solve for the characteristic polynomial, we have:

$$|A - \lambda
 I| = 0 \rightarrow \lambda^2 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_{1,2} = 0$$

Now, we take a eigenvalue and use it to solve:

$$[A - \lambda_1 I]v_1 = 0$$

We then need a generalized eigenvector and use:

$$[A - \lambda_1 I]v_2 = v_1$$

We should get:

$$\displaystyle v_1 = (1, 2), v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{4},0\right)$$

Comment: What do you think about mine, Amzoti? I thought the OP wanted to solve the system, but he/she is silence. :-(

Comment: @BabakS.: I love how you used the differential operator approach, so the OP now has two approaches. I think s/he realized the issue and likely abandoned the thread, but +1 for using the D operator my friend! Regards

Comment: Both great approaches! +1 for you and +1 for Babak!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y$, so your system would be: $$
\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x'=4x-2y \\
            y'=8x-4y
        \end{array}
    \right.
~~~~~\text{or}~~~~~
\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            Dx=4x-2y \\
            Dy=8x-4y
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ We can be go further: $$\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            (D-4)x+2y=0 \\
            (D+4)y-8x=0
        \end{array}
    \right.$$ Trying to solve this system as an ordinary system we get: $$\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            D^2x=0 \\
            D^2y=0
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

Comment: @Babak S:Excellent(As always)*¸.•´¸.•*¨) ¸.•*¨)¸.•*¨) ,.-~*´¨¯¨`*•~-.¸,.-~*´¨¯¨`*•~-.¸,.-~*´¨¯¨`*•~-.¸,.-~* ¯´¨ ¨`*•~-.¸..... *•~-.¸,.-~*´¨¯¨`*•~-.¸,.-~*´¨¯¨`*•~-.¸,.-~* ¯´¨ ¨`*•~-.¸..

Comment: @ℬaℌaK S:✽✾wishing you ever increasing success✿❀